# What is the benefit of reducing inflammation when producing antibodies?

Tags: physiology, immunology

We just learned in lecture that IL-10 promotes the formation of plasma cells over memory cells. Which seemed strange to me as IL-10 also reduces inflammation, and I figure you would want inflammation as it will help antibodies reach the site of infection.

My question is, why would the body want to reduce inflammation and produce more antibodies at the same time?